# Unable to pull image from private GCR from Container Optimized Compute Engine

Tags: docker, google-compute-engine, google-container-registry

Can't get what I'm doing wrong...

Performed next steps on fresh compute engine instance based on Container Optimized OS:

- `docker-credential-gcr configure-docker`
- `sudo docker run --detach --name=echo --net=esp_net gcr.io/around-dev/firebase-service-image:latest`

And got the following:

> Unable to find image 'gcr.io/around-dev/firebase-service-image:latest' locally
>   Pulling repository gcr.io/around-dev/firebase-service-image
>   docker: unauthorized: authentication required.
>   See 'docker run --help'.

Then tried actually to login with `docker-credential-gcr gcr-login` and run, but still got the same error.
After all my .docker/.config.json looks like:

```
 {
        "auths": {},
        "credHelpers": {
                "asia.gcr.io": "gcr",
                "eu.gcr.io": "gcr",
                "gcr.io": "gcr",
                "staging-k8s.gcr.io": "gcr",
                "us.gcr.io": "gcr"
        }
```

Obviously no credentials stored. Can someone explain to me what I'm doing wrong? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 15):

#### Why you're seeing this

You're seeing this error because you ran `docker-credential-gcr configure-docker` without `sudo` and then `sudo docker run ...`. When running `sudo docker`, it looks for the configuration file in `/root/.docker/` and doesn't find anything, thus throwing the `authentication required` error.

#### Why running `sudo docker-credential-gcr configure-docker` won't fix it

When you're running COS, you don't have write access to all directories. Only a few directories are writable and `/root` isn't one of them. Because of that, running  `docker-credential-gcr` as root fails since it can't write the docker config file inside the `$HOME` directory (that happens to be `/root`).

More details on writable directories: https://cloud.google.com/container-optimized-os/docs/concepts/security#filesystem

#### Fixing it

**1 - Override `$HOME`**

`sudo HOME=/home/root /usr/bin/docker-credential-gcr configure-docker`

`sudo HOME=/home/root docker run --detach --name=echo --net=esp_net gcr.io/around-dev/firebase-service-image:latest`

**2 - Manually specify a config file location**

You can also include the path to the docker config directory with each command. For example, if you know docker is configured with credentials in the `/home/root/.docker` directory, you could run the following command: `sudo docker --config /home/root/.docker pull gcr.io/my-project/alpine:3.2`

Answer (score 1):

If you have a private VPC and an instance without an external IP, you can get a timeout error. A way to fix this is the enable `private_ip_google_access` on a subnet level. This let's you access google resources with a few exceptions without needing an external IP address on your instance.

Comment: On GCP, VM with no public IP, took me whole day to find this.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem when I wanted to push an image to GCR. I also ran docker with `sudo`. I solved my problem by adding my user to the docker usergroup, as found on the [docker postinstall guide](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/linux-postinstall/):

```
sudo groupadd docker
sudo usermod -aG docker $USER
```

Then logout and login again

Comment: Make sure you log out and back in again rather than restarting the instance. In my case this was resetting the docker group

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use gcloud-image in docker, which is a docker base image himself

Assuming that you have service account key file in $PWD/gcr-auth.json
Just need pass down docker-socks and your service json key in volume

```
docker run -exec \
-v $PWD:$PWD \
-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
google/cloud-sdk \
sh -c
 'gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file=/somepath/gcr-auth.json && gcloud docker -- pull gcr.io/some-project/myimage:latest'
```

After pulling done, the image is back on the host

Answer (score -1):

I'm on COS and also had similar problems. The documentation for COS makes it seem like it should be as simple as running 2 commands.

```
$ docker-credential-gcr configure-docker
$ docker run --rm gcr.io/<your-project>/<your-image>
```

The file gets created in `~/.docker/config.json`. But I couldn't pull the private image to run it. I can successfully pull public images.

After bashing my head against the wall for most of the day I tried the login command `docker-credential-gcr gcr-login`. I have 2factor auth setup on my account and when I ran that command it gave me a URL that I had to visit to enter an auth token. After I followed those instructions I can now successfully pull images from the private registry.

I'm unsure if this is the correct workflow as it is not covered in the documentation.